# Column selection using values found in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I start with a df that has `key` (patient ID) and each month labeled `Month1` through `Month12`. In each cell for a given key and month, there is either a `1` or `0` which signifies whether or not a patient (`key`) had insurance coverage over that month, (`1`=True, `0`=False). In another df I have about 105 columns which includes a `Key`, `Date1` and `Date2`. My goal is to find rows that had insurance coverage between the dates provided (inclusive). I want those rows specifically. The caveat is that if any of the rows for a given patient (`key`) don't have insurance coverage for the dates provided (and the time in between the dates), then I want to remove all rows for that patient.

So initially, I merged the two dataframes together and created two additional columns `StartMonth`, `EndMonth` which are derived from `date1` and `date2`, respectively. I now need to check that the patient had insurance between this time frame.

For example, in the dataframe below which has 6 of the 12 months (so it's not too large). The first row would be eliminated because the patient didn't have insurance coverage between the `StartMonth` and `EndMonth`. The second row would be kept because there was insurance coverage during their `StartMonth` and `EndMonth`. And rows 3 and 4 would be eliminated because even though row 3 does have insurance over the dates, row 4 does not, so all rows of the patient ('key') will be removed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['1312', '1345', '5555', '5555'], 
              'Month1': [1, 1, 1,1],
              'Month2': [1, 1, 1,1],
              'Month3': [0, 1, 1,1],
              'Month4': [0, 1, 0,0],
              'Month5': [0, 1, 0,0],
              'Month6': [0, 1, 0,0],
              'Date1': [20120304, 20120102, 20120203,20120402],
              'Date2': [20120405,20120104,20120502,20120501],
              'StartMonth': [3,1,1,4],
              'EndMonth': [4,1,3,5]})
df[['KEY','Date1','Date2','StartMonth','EndMonth','Month1', 'Month2','Month3','Month4','Month5','Month6']]
```

Original dataframe:

```
    KEY     Date1       Date2       StartMonth  EndMonth    Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  Month6
0   1312    20120304    20120405    3           4           1       1       0       0       0       0
1   1345    20120102    20120104    1           1           1       1       1       1       1       1
2   5555    20120203    20120502    1           3           1       1       1       0       0       0
3   5555    20120402    20120501    4           5           1       1       1       0       0       0
```

The final result :

```
    KEY     Date1       Date2       StartMonth  EndMonth    Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  Month6
1   1345    20120102    20120104    1           1           1       1       1       1       1       1
```

My initial approach was to find the columns that I needed by concatenating the word 'Month' with the value found in the `StartMonth` and `EndMonth`. After doing this, I thought I could create boundaries for the insurance time frame, however, I'm getting errors with this approach. I am very early in the process but I am thinking that this might not be the best approach. Any help would be great, this is a tough question.

```
df.groupby('KEY').filter(lambda x: x['Month'+ x.iloc[x]['StartMonth']]==1.0)

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Another method I'm working on is creating a list of column names which I derived for the startmonth and endmonth of each row. Then I was thinking I can include these column names into a `.filter()` and see if the range of columns has a 0.

```
MonthRange = []
StartMonthStr = []
EndMonthStr = []
StartMonthInt = df['StartMonth'].tolist()
EndMonthInt = df['EndMonth'].tolist()

for x,y in zip(StartMonthInt, EndMonthInt):
    sm = 'Month' + str(x)
    em = 'Month' + str(y)
    diff = y - x
    MonthRange.append(diff)
    StartMonthStr.append(sm)
    EndMonthStr.append(em)
```

Comment: Is there additional processing you want to do with the data once you've generated the dataframe in your example?  The reason I ask is because the "Month1", "Month2", etc. columns may be an unnecessary step.

Comment: I think this is wrong, you will also retain the last row correct?

Comment: Why wouldn't you keep both the 2nd and last rows?

Comment: Ok, it would be best to post the final final dataframe you're looking for, including the removed Month columns.

Comment: I clarified the question. The reason the second and the last row is not retained is because they belong to the group 'Key' and since the 3 row is in the same grouping and it is removed this will remove all other rows in that grouping. The final dataframe is posted. Removing the month columns are not critical to this question. It might be worth mentioning that this df has 120 total columns, I've merely taken a subset of the important fields for this question.

Comment: You say `StartMonth`, `EndMonth` are derived from `df2.Date1`,`Date2`. But please explain what that dataframe  `df2` actually is (insurance? policy? eligibility? treatment?)? These all have no connection with `df1.Month1`, `Month2`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want.

```
def condition(row):
    return row['KEY'] if not all(row['Month'+str(i)] \
           for i in range(row['aStartMonth'], row['aEndMonth']+1)) else None

df = df[~df['KEY'].isin(df.apply(condition, axis=1))]

#       Date1     Date2        KEY  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  \
# 0  20120304  20120405  100000003       1       1       1       1       1   

#    Month6  aEndMonth  aStartMonth  
# 0       1          4            3
```

Comment: This seems to be working, however, if I wanted to groupby 'Key' and another column how can that be done. Can that be incorporated into your solution. This wasn't part of the original question, but this fact now seems important to the solution.

Comment: I can start new question or update df with a new group.

Comment: @MartyB ,please do start a new question. Thks

Answer (score 0):

First define a function to check your logic:

```
check_date = lambda grp: grp.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[x.aStartMonth+2:x.aEndMonth+3].mean(), axis=1).eq(1).all()
```

Then apply this function to each group and filter the data:

```
df.groupby('KEY').filter(check_date)
Out[650]: 
      Date1     Date2        KEY  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  \
0  20120304  20120405  100000003       1       1       1       1       1   

   Month6  aEndMonth  aStartMonth  
0       1          4            3
```

Comment: @jp_data_analysis, please see the OP's comments.